# How to make rounded faces to model a human face?

Tags: modeling

I would like to know how to curve edges and faces in order to make a nose or a cheek. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I like to use a mirrored dynamic topography "dyntopo" sculpt for faces.

Comment: You can't "curve  edges and faces" they are the smallest fundamental undeformable units of a 3D model. They can however be subdivided to create apparently curved surfaces. See [some tutorials about it](https://www.google.pt/search?tbm=vid&q=blender+beginner+face)

Comment: You might use a subdivision surface modifier on multiple faces, which smoothens the difference between the faces.

Answer (score 2):

Edges are by definition straight, and faces by definition planar. A strip of edges or faces can be curved by offsetting the direction of each a tiny bit to the former.

Luckily, you don't (in most cases) have to do this by hand. For examples of how it works and looks, try out the sculpting tools sometime!

**EDIT** as Duane Dibbley points out below, it IS in fact possible to curve faces that have more than 3 vertices but it may cause some rendering oddities. The reason I did not consider it is because most applications I import models into accept tris (tri-verticed faces) only. Check your target application (if any) before attempting this.

Comment: It is actually possible to make bent faces, but it will cause strange shading artifacts. Just move one or more vertices of a quad or n-gon, to make the vertices non-coplanar.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley You are of course entirely correct... I'm way too used to thinking solely in tris. I may have to remove this answer then...

Comment: @DuaneDibbley This is correct, but quads and ngons are internally still split up in tris. The polygon does not have a smooth shape as such, but it is a combination of more tris with smooth shading. They are not really curved or smooth.

Comment: @Dimali You are right, of course. I don't really do this, so I never considered what actually happens "under the hood".